# Email is not sending through MyAsp.Net Server

Tags: asp.net, email, c#-4.0, smtp

I am facing some unexpected problem in sending email which i have never faced before. I have hosted my application on the MyASP.NET server.
My Email Domain is purchased from VERIO.
I am sending mails using by my application, which is hosted on MYASP.NET server.
It means I am trying to connect VERIO SMTP server for sending mails from MYASP.NET server.

**It is not giving me any error on sending mail click button from my application. but also email is not going to recipient.** 
The code which I am using are as follows:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();           
mail.From = new MailAddress("museum@essenrfid.net");    
mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text); 
//set the content 
mail.Subject = "Test Subject"; 
mail.Body = "TEst Contect"; 
//send the message 
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.verio.com", 587); 
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
//IMPORANT:  Your smtp login email MUST be same as your FROM address. 
NetworkCredential Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXXXx", "XXXXX"); 
smtp.Credentials = Credentials;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

NOTE: My email was working till yesterday from last one month but I have not changed code & it was not working from yesterday. What could be the issue. Any Idea anyone faced this problem before.
Please help.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: If it working yesterday. Then there is no issue with code. My suggestion is please check you SMTP server subscription. Because you are using third party smtp server. So there is chance that it create this issue.

Comment: but have you faced this issue earlier.

Comment: Yes but issue is not exactly same. For my case I am using send grid for sending email.

Comment: what should i check with SMTP server, coz I have talked with them they are telling that it is not their issue. what should i asked them can you please tell me precisely.